# Center rotating arrow in Konva.js

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I'm writting you cause I'm actually stuck. I have to create an arrow with Konva.js (I have personalized mine according to a model : https://konvajs.github.io/docs/overview.html).

I've attached my JS file (to create the arrow), the CSS and the HTML file which displays the result by calling the JS file.

Here is my problem : When I enter a value in the HTML file (direction of the wind), I'd like my arrow to rotate of the angle indicated (the direction). It could be 45°, 90°, 135°,... (so NE, E, SE,...). But actually, my arrow rotates but also moves also on the screen around the top-left point. I don't know why. I would like it to only rotates on itself. How would you do ?

I've seen it could work with offsetX and offsetY but don't know if there is a better solution or how to use it. That's why I am requiring your help.

```js
function draw_fleche_vent(direction){
  var direction = direction//new Konva.Transformer({
  //   rotationSnaps: [0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315, 360],
  // });
  // var force = "";
  // get
  // var rotationSnaps = transformer.rotationSnaps();

  // set
  // transformer.rotationSnaps([0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315, 360]);

  var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
  });

  var layer = new Konva.Layer();


  /*
  * create a triangle shape by defining a
  * drawing function which draws a triangle
  */
  var triangle = new Konva.Shape({
    sceneFunc: function (context, shape) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(225, 10);
      context.lineTo(150, 190);
      context.quadraticCurveTo(230, 90, 300, 190);
      context.closePath();
      //context.offset({context.width/2, context.height/2});
      //context.position({context.width/2,context.height/2});
      context.fillStrokeShape(shape);
    },
    fill: '#FF5757',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4
  });

  //var c = document.getElementById(context);
  //context.rotate(direction * Math.PI / 180) ;
  

  triangle.rotate(direction);
  layer.add(triangle);
  stage.add(layer);
  

// console.log('ca marche');

    // switch (direction) {
    //   case 0: 
    //     // ayer.add(triangle);.add(direction);
    //     // add the triangle shape to the layer
    //     layer.add(triangle);
    //     // triangle.rotate(0);

    //     // add the layer to the stage
    //     stage.add(layer);
    //   console.log('on est dans le switch 0');
    //   break;
    //   case 45: 
    //     //context.rotate();
    //     // add the triangle shape to the layer
    //     layer.add(triangle);
    //     triangle.rotate(45);
    //     // add the layer to the stage
    //     stage.add(layer);
    //   console.log('on est dans le switch 45');
    //   break;
    //   case 90:
    //     // context.rotate(Math.PI / 180);
    //     // add the triangle shape to the layer
    //     layer.add(triangle);
    //     triangle.rotate(90);
    //     // add the layer to the stage
    //     stage.add(layer);

    //     console.log('on est dans le switch 90');
    //     break; 
    //   case 135: 
    //     // add the triangle shape to the layer
    //     layer.add(triangle);
    //     triangle.rotate(135);
    //     // add the layer to the stage
    //     stage.add(layer);
    //   console.log('on est dans le switch 135');
    //   break;
    //   case 180: 
    //     // add the triangle shape to the layer
    //     layer.add(triangle);
    //     triangle.rotate(180);
    //     // add the layer to the stage
    //     stage.add(layer);
    //   console.log('on est dans le switch 180');
    //   break;
    //   case 225: 
    //     // add the triangle shape to the layer
    //     layer.add(triangle);
    //     triangle.rotate(225);
    //     // add the layer to the stage
    //     stage.add(layer);
    //   console.log('on est dans le switch 225');
    //   break;
    //   case 270: 
    //     // add the triangle shape to the layer
    //     layer.add(triangle);
    //     triangle.rotate(270);
    //     // add the layer to the stage
    //     stage.add(layer);
    //   console.log('on est dans le switch 270');
    //   break;
    //   case 315: 
    //     // add the triangle shape to the layer
    //     layer.add(triangle);
    //     triangle.rotate(315);
    //     // add the layer to the stage
    //     stage.add(layer);
    //   console.log('on est dans le switch 315');
    //   break;
    //   case 360: 
    //     // add the triangle shape to the layer
    //     layer.add(triangle);
    //     triangle.rotate(360);
    //     // add the layer to the stage
    //     stage.add(layer);
    //     console.log('on est dans le switch 360');
    //   break;
    // }

  // add the triangle shape to the layer
  // layer.add(triangle);

  // add the layer to the stage
  // stage.add(layer);
}

// function rotation(){
//   triangle.rotate(45);
//   stage.draw();
//   console.log('loaded');
// }
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src="konva.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "fleche.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Arrow - Try</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
         draw_fleche_vent(45);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If my answer to your question about rotating shapes was helpful please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

The way that almost all computer drawing libraries work is to use points and rectangles. Your need to think about your arrow being drawn in a rectangular space.

*Note that Konva is a little unusual in graphics libraries in that ellipse-drawn shapes have their rotation point defaulted to their centres. And there is a great explanation of the offset/rotation scenario on the Konva docs website [here](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/posts/Position_vs_Offset.html).*

In your code where the triangle shape is created you use

```
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(225, 10);
...
```

The starting point (beginPath) is the top-left corner of a rectangle that contains the drawing. So that is point(0,0).

Any position changes, or rotation changes, that are applied to the shape use this point as the centre of movement.

As you have seen, this means that rotation appears to move the shape unexpectedly.

The rotation point can be moved via the offSet(x, y) function. As its name suggests, this moves the rotation point by the given values.

You have to decide exactly where the rotation point should be moved to, and this depends on the shape you have drawn. A good starting point is usually to use the centre of the rectangle surrounding the shape.

```
var dX = node.width()/2;
var dY = node.height()/2;
node.offset(dX, dY)
```

Note that changing the offset will move the shape so you need to re-position the shape with

```
node.position({x:node.x() + dX, y: node.y() + dY})
```

Lastly - when posting code samples try to cut them down to a point where they illustrate the basic problem. So leave out all the code that is commented, except for useful comments, next time.

```js
// Set up the canvas / stage
var div = $('#container');

var stage = new Konva.Stage({container: 'container', width: div.width(), height: div.height()});
var layer = new Konva.Layer({draggable: false});
stage.add(layer)

// make a triangle 
 var triangle = new Konva.Shape({
    sceneFunc: function (context, shape) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(25, 00);
      context.lineTo(0, 60);
      context.quadraticCurveTo(0, 60, 50, 60);
      context.closePath();
      context.fillStrokeShape(shape);
    },
    fill: 'cyan',
    stroke: 'transparent'
  });

// make a rect hsape to illustrate the rectangle that the triangle is drawn into
var rect = new Konva.Rect({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 50,
    height: 60,
    stroke: 'magenta',
    strokeWidth: 1
  });

// add both to a group
var group1 = new Konva.Group();
group1.position({x:50, y:50})
group1.add(triangle)
group1.add(rect)
  
// note the size of the group before we stick the cross to it as the cross affects the size.
// we will use this for offset and position later
var szWidth = group1.getClientRect().width/2;
var szHeight = group1.getClientRect().height/2;

// make a big red X to show the rotation point.
var cross = new Konva.Shape({
    name: 'cross',
    sceneFunc: function (context, shape) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(0, 10);
      context.lineTo(10, 0);
      context.moveTo(0, 0);
      context.lineTo(10, 10);
      context.fillStrokeShape(shape);
    },
    strokeWidth: 2,
    stroke: 'red',
    x: -5,
    y: -5
  });

group1.add(cross)

// clone the first group to make a second, overriding the x position
var group3 = group1.clone({
  x: 120,
  opacity: .4  // give this one low opacity to make it faint.
});  

// clone a node and override the x position - this is the one we will spin.
var group2 = group1.clone({
  x: 120
});  

// load all into the layer
layer.add(group1)
layer.add(group3)
layer.add(group2)

// offset group2 drawing & rotating point (call this the origin)
group2.offsetX(szWidth);
group2.offsetY(szHeight);

// IMPORTANT: but now we need to move the shape to compensate for the offset of the 'origin'.
group2.move({x: szWidth, y: szHeight})

// move the big red cross to show where the origin is now.
var cross2 = group2.findOne('.cross');
cross2.move({x: szWidth, y: szHeight});

stage.draw()

// hook the button click event to make the rotation happen
$('#rotate10').on('click', function(){
  group1.rotate(10);
  group2.rotate(10);
  layer.draw();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/2.5.1/konva.min.js"></script>
<div>
<p>Left arrow is rotating without offset. The right arrow has both offset() and move() applied.</p>
<button id='rotate10' class='btn'>Rotate 10 degrees clockwise</button>
</div>
<div id='container' style="position: absolute; top: 40px; z-index: -1; display: inline-block; left: 0px;  width: 260px; height: 140px; background-color: silver;"></div>
```